# How to define edge_func parameter in dgl.nn.pytorch.conv.NNConv?

Tags: graph, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a graph with nodes, edges, and edge features. I want to make a model with `SAGEConv` but `SAGEConv` only look at node features. So I thought of making node feature by aggregating edge features of each node and I found out about `NNConv`, where they're able to do that. The problem is I'm not sure how to use `NNConv`, especially what do I do with `edge_func` that is required as a parameter for `NNConv`?

Let say I have 3 nodes and 4 edges, each edge has 2 features, and I want the each nodes to have 2 features as well. I defined `edge_func` to be

```
  edge_func = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(2, 2), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(2, 4))
```

and edge_feature to be

```
  tensor([[2., 3.],
          [3., 1.],
          [0., 4.],
          [1., 1.]])
```

and build a DGLGraph with that. However after computing the layer

```
  NNConv(in_feats=2, out_feats=2, edge_nn, aggregator_type='max')
```

in the forward function

```
  feature = self.layer(self.graph, feature, edge_feature)
```

returns feature (it was originally tensor of zeros) as

```
  tensor([[-inf, -inf],
          [0., 0.],
          [0., 0.]], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should ask this on the DGL forum https://discuss.dgl.ai/

Comment: @Karl thanks! i'm a complete newbie to this